# how to display the date retrieved through a button

Tags: date, button, android-studio, displayobject

I have code for, date which is used for automatic storage through a button
Now I also need to display date once I press this button.How to do this

```
    public class datebutton extends Activity {
protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);

    final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.date);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Date today = new Date();

            //Convert to calendar Object
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.setTime(today);

            int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int dayOfMonth = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        }
    });
}
```

}

My activity xml code is

```
    <Button
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:onClick="DAte"
android:text="DATE"
android:textSize="27sp"
android:id="@+id/date" />
```

Advance thaks for helping me

Comment: What effect did you expect to see and what are you actually seeing?

Comment: This code is for retrieving date from android mobile but it is not being displayed.I want to know how to do this?